# Linearizing the Inverted Pendulum

Tags: calculus

[image]

Hi. I don't understand how to obtain $d$, in particular in the example of an inverted pendulum. Can you help me?

Comment: You calculate $d$ using equation 48. $$d(k) = \delta x(k+ 1) - A\delta x(k) - B \delta u(k)$$

Comment: thanks. If I do how you suggest, how I obtain zero in the first row of the vector?

Comment: The snippet you give here is not enough for me to be sure what $\Delta$ means in this usage, so I cannot do that calculation.